# CSS всплывающая кнопка

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование, вёрстка

Делал по предложенному примеру всплывающую кнопку/ссылку, но есть проблема.
При наведении на ul я хочу, чтобы кнопка появлялась всегда в фиксированном месте возле нижней границы ul (как на фото), сейчас же она появляется снизу под изображением, заходя на изображение.

Как нужно

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужна помощь

```css
.mycls ul {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
}

.show .mycls a {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
}


/* Обертка */

.mycls li {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.show {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(100px);
  -moz-transform: translateY(100px);
  -ms-transform: translateY(100px);
  -o-transform: translateY(100px);
  transform: translateY(100px);
}


/* Наведение */

ul:hover .show {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
  -moz-transform: translateY(0px);
  -ms-transform: translateY(0px);
  -o-transform: translateY(0px);
  transform: translateY(0px);
  position: absolute;
}

.mycls {
  width: 220px;
  height: 310px;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid #808080;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
  /*margin between item*/
}
```

```html
<ul class="mycls">

  <li align="center">
    <!--  <div>
            <div>@Html.ActionLink(@Html.DisplayFor(m => item.Name.Tool).ToString(), "Item", new { id = item.ToolID }, new { @class = "div-name" })</div>
                <div class="div-price">Стоимость: @item.Price.ToString("# руб").</div>
                <div>
                    @{
        var img = "";
        try
        {
            var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(item.ImageData);
            img = string.Format("data:;base64,{0}", base64);
            <img src='@img' class="img-responsive" width="220" height="300" />
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            <span class="form-control-static">Нет изображения!</span>
        }

                    }
                </div>   -->
    <img src="http://svarkahome.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/delaem-svarochnyj-apparat-postojannogo-toka-svoimi_1.jpg" class="img-responsive" width="220" height="200" />
    </div>

    <div class="show">
      <a><input type="button" value="В корзину" class="btn btn-default btn-outline" /></a>
    </div>


  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `.mycls li { height: 100%; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Спасибо!

```
.mycls li {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Если вы считаете этот ответ правильным, отметьте его как решение